# Can a primary key also be a foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Let's imagine a scenario where users have pages which have articles (none or many) in them. I would have these three tables: `user`,`page`,`article`. In this case `user` table would have primary key `username`, and page would have two primary keys `username` and `page_name` (page name would be fe. "news" which is unique name in user's pages). Now as I said article has two primary keys of which `username` is a primary key but also refers to `user` table. Is it possible that in `page` table I set `username` as a primary key but also as a foreign key that refers to `page` table?

Thanks.

Comment: No, primary key can not be a foreign key.

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. It can have multiple unique keys, but only one of them is primary.

Comment: But still username obviously refers to user in page table.

Comment: I think what you're thinking of is a composite key. PRIMARY KEY(username, page_name) is valid.

create table page ( username text, page_name text, PRIMARY KEY(username, page_name), FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES user(username) ... );

Comment: Your idea is totally bad you are using article table with primary key and also with username fk not possible

Comment: This is not only "in MySQL". This is about - SQL in general. To be more specific, this is about RDB - read about foreign keys and primary keys. What they are and why you question has no sense